# Javascript change color on click and keep the same color

Tags: javascript, css, colors, background-color

I have currently the following code:

```
<li><a href="index.php" id="1" onclick="document.getElementById('1').style.background = '#8B4513';">Weblog</a></li>
```

This changes the color, but because it opens index.php the color won't stay at the same color. It returns to the original color.

How can i keep it the same color, in a different page?

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to the color of a *visited link*?

Comment: simple solution would be to use cookie to keep track of such selection. On load of the new page, you can check the flag and set the color.

Comment: if i clicked another link, would the previous link i clicked go back to the original color? or retain it's "clicked" color? because *visited links* and *selected links* have different implementations and effects - and your question sounds a bit of both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, an ID can not start with a number.

You have to catch the selected page on the server side and give it a class like selected and use CSS to do something like:

```
li.selected a
{
    background: #8B4513;
}
```

If you have no clue how to set a selected page with PHP, read this article: http://darkstar-media.blogspot.com/2009/04/css-page-selected-with-php.html

Comment: An `id` *may* start with a number in HTML5.

Comment: It's a bad habit, so really not.

Answer (score 1):

From the code provided it looks like you are trying to style an element once a user has clicked a link.

Javascript seems unnecessary here. I would just use the :visited css pseudo-class to style the element.

For example;

```
a:visited { text-decoration: line-through; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is clientside, which means that any changes done happens in a way on the user's screen.

PHP is serverside. You send a request to the server, it processes the request and displays the output.

If you want to highlight the current webpage, this is not the way to do it.

I'd suggest you add a line of PHP on each file in the `li a`-list. For example:

```
<?php if ($URL == 'index.php') echo 'class="selected"'; ?>
```

And using CSS to make the link with the class selected red ones.